# Как аннотации (к примеру, @Retention) могут аннотировать сами себя?

Tags: java, аннотации

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface Retention {
    /**
     * Returns the retention policy.
     * @return the retention policy
     */
    RetentionPolicy value();
}
```

Тут видно, что аннотация @Retention стоит собственно над объявлением самой аннотации @Retention. И такой трюк можно делать не только с мета-аннотациями, а и с обычными, рукотворными. Где происходит магия при загрузке классов аннотаций, и почему это всё работает?

Comment: Приведи пример кода где это используется.

Comment: @RomanC этот код из официальной поставки JDK и он используется при обьявлении любых других аннотаций. Что тут ещё приводить можно?

Answer (score 0):

Никакой магии нет. Все аннотации обрабатываются на этапе компиляции. В общем случае, аннотирование аннотации дает наследование. На примере Spring, есть аннотация `@Component`, которая сигнализирует, что аннотированный класс является бином, который должен быть обработан Spring-ом. Так же есть аннотация `@Service`, которая якобы сообщает нам, что аннотированный класс является сервисом. На самом деле аннотация `@Service` помечена аннотацией `@Component`, поэтому Spring также понимает такой класс как свой бин. А название Service дано просто для удобочитаемости кода. Вы можете написать свои аннотации, пометить их другими аннотациями, тем самым унаследуете свойства этих аннотаций. К `@RetentionPolicy` и `@Target` это не относится, они обрабатываются по-своему. Для более глубокого погружения в тему гуглите Java Annotation Processing.

Comment: Хотелось как раз "более глубокого погружения" в базовые аннотации. Потому, что насчёт спринговых Component-ов известно довольно широко. А вот особенности обработки @Retention и им подобных, думаю, мало кто знает.